# Cordova App Loader relative path

Tags: cordova

I have just integrated [cordova-app-loader](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader) into my app.
But I get this error:

```
GET .../temporary/app/img/wellcome.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Seems like under app-loader, the CSS is placed at `/temporary/app` which causes the relative path to be different.

Which is the best practice to solve this?

1. Add all of my resources to app-loader manifest.
2. Force the CSS to non-relative path.
3. Any other idea.